# Risk Management PineScript

Tags: pine-script

i want to test a simple idea in pinescript

Increase or decrease my order size in cumulatively percentages , depending on the result of the last trade

Ex: If last trade was a win trade, increase x% of start order size.

Ex: If last trade was a lose trade, decrease x% start order size.

For simplicity, order size starts with being fixed, lets say 10,000 USD.

Let's suppose i lose 3 trades in a row and i'm decreasing 10% my start order size for each loss trade

My next order size should be 70% my start order size (10,000 USD).

Btw, pyramiding = 0

Thanks for you attention! :)

Answer (score 0):

To access the last trade PnL, that's this variable
`strategy.closedtrades.profit(strategy.closedtrades - 1)`
Don't forget to take into account the commissions/fees, reducing them from your PnL

```
var float initial_qty_size = 10000
var float qty_size = initial_qty_size

last_trade_pnL = strategy.closedtrades.profit(strategy.closedtrades - 1) - strategy.closedtrades.commission(strategy.closedtrades - 1)
if last_trade_pnL > 0
    qty_size := initial_qty_size * 1.10 // increasing of 10%
else
    qty_size := initial_qty_size * 0.9 // decreasing of 10%
```

Comment: Hello Daveatt, the order size is changing between 9000 and 11000, but not cumulatively. Need to store the qty_size values, any ideas?

Comment: A dirty solution that could work

```
var float initial_qty_size = 10000
var int count_gains = 0
var int count_losses = 0

last_trade_pnL = strategy.closedtrades.profit(strategy.closedtrades - 1) - strategy.closedtrades.commission(strategy.closedtrades - 1)
if last_trade_pnL > 0
    count_gains += 1
    count_losses := 0
    qty_size := initial_qty_size * (1 + (count_gains / 10))
else
    count_losses += 1
    count_gains := 0
    qty_size := initial_qty_size * (1 - (count_losses / 10))
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: https://prnt.sc/Z71CWtFeVUqD - Btw, what do you mean by dirty solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's missing something in this code.

You have to propagate the current quantity-size
to do so you replace:
initial_qty_size by  qty_size[1].

And you add:
if barstate.isfirst
qty_size = initial_qty_size

Comment: var float initial_qty_size = 10000...
var float qty_size...

if barstate.isfirst...
   qty_size = initial_qty_size...

last_trade_pnL = strategy.closedtrades.profit(strategy.closedtrades - 1) - strategy.closedtrades.commission(strategy.closedtrades - 1)...
if last_trade_pnL > 0...
    qty_size := qty_size[1] * 1.10 // increasing of 10% ???? But how many times before you blow your cover ???...
else...
    qty_size := qty_size[1] * 0.9 // decreasing of 10%...

Comment: Elise, thanks for responding. But it's not working properly

Comment: var float qty_size =0.0........qty_size := initial_qty_size.................. // the thing is that you dont have to calculate on each bar but only when a trade has just closed

Answer (score 0):

```
var float minSize = 10000
var float maxSize = 100000
var float qty_size = 0.0
var bool calculateNewSize = false
var float last_trade_pnL = 0.0
if barstate.isfirst
    qty_size := minSize
else
    qty_size := qty_size[1]
if bar_index == strategy.closedtrades.exit_bar_index(strategy.closedtrades - 1)
    calculateNewSize := true
last_trade_pnL := strategy.closedtrades.profit(strategy.closedtrades - 1)
if calculateNewSize
    if last_trade_pnL > 0
        qty_size := math.round(qty_size[1] * 1.10) // increasing of 10%
    else
        qty_size := math.round(qty_size[1] * 0.9) // decreasing of 10%
if qty_size > maxSize
    qty_size := maxSize
if qty_size < minSize
    qty_size := minSize
plot(qty_size)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// Or : shorter but less clear
//
    var float minSize = 10000
    var float maxSize = 100000
    var float qty_size = 0.0
    var float last_trade_pnL = 0.0
    qty_size := barstate.isfirst ? minSize : qty_size[1]
    last_trade_pnL := strategy.closedtrades.profit(strategy.closedtrades - 1)
    if bar_index == strategy.closedtrades.exit_bar_index(strategy.closedtrades - 1)
        qty_size := last_trade_pnL > 0 ? math.round(qty_size[1] * 1.10) : math.round(qty_size[1] * 0.9)
    qty_size := qty_size > maxSize ? maxSize : qty_size < minSize ? minSize : qty_size
    plot(qty_size)
```

Comment: Elise thanks answering, but I recommend testing it before commenting, none of your suggestions work correctly, order size stay fixed (10k).

Comment: But I do have tested it and it works just fine for me. I know were your problem is. You should look backwards near the biginning of the history, the size grows very quickly and then stays put. The reason is that your strategy is too good, it makes very few losses.